# Is there any Richtext(text, images) solution in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a project that it would display contents of topics and replies. There are always many images in it. It there any possible method to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

As I understund, you should write UITableViewCell subclass for this.
And compose into it UIImageView's and UILabel's what you need. 
In code you can dynamically calculate Cell Height and add new UIImageView's